# LST from Lansat 5 in GEE using Code from Ermida et al

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-surface-temperature, landsat-5

I am working with the code at the following link from Ermida et al. in Google Earth Engine https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst

I would like to work with Landsat 5 surface temperature data. Unfortunately, I am not able to adjust the fields in the code to work with Landsat 5 instead of Landsat 8 (changing the code worked for Landsat 7).

What do I have to do to generate Landsat 5 data in GEE?

Below you can find what I did so far. Using this code, no results are shown.

```
// link to the code that computes the Landsat LST
var LandsatLST = require('users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst:modules/Landsat_LST.js')


// select region of interest, date range, and landsat satellite

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-80.74, -5.08, -80.51, -5.26]);

var satellite = 'L5';

var date_start = '2010-06-01';

var date_end = '2010-06-30';

var use_ndvi = true;

// get landsat collection with added variables: NDVI, FVC, TPW, EM, LST

var LandsatColl = LandsatLST.collection(satellite, date_start, date_end, geometry, use_ndvi)
print(LandsatColl)

// select the first feature

var exImage = LandsatColl.first();

var cmap1 = ['blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];

var cmap2 = ['F2F2F2','EFC2B3','ECB176','E9BD3A','E6E600','63C600','00A600']; 

Map.centerObject(geometry)

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('TPW'),{min:0.0, max:60.0, palette:cmap1},'TCWV')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('TPWpos'),{min:0.0, max:9.0, palette:cmap1},'TCWVpos')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('FVC'),{min:0.0, max:1.0, palette:cmap2}, 'FVC')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('EM'),{min:0.9, max:1.0, palette:cmap1}, 'Emissivity')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('B6'),{min:290, max:320, palette:cmap1}, 'TIR BT')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('LST'),{min:290, max:320, palette:cmap1}, 'LST')

Map.addLayer(exImage.multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2),{bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'], min:0, max:0.3}, 'RGB'
```

Comment: There are not images in Landsat 5 product for that area with your dates range. So, you cannot get any result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!